# Large files from SMB over slow VPN

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, samba

We have an SMB share setup that can only be accessed over our VPN.

Once a month I have to download a large file (10GB+) but its a slow process as to access the SMB I have to be connected to our VPN which is painfully slow.

Is it possible to write a script to download that file by tunneling over the VPN? e.g. so it's only the script is on the VPN and the rest of my computer is still on my normal network connection

Comment: You can't configure a VPN to "only run a script" but you can configure the VPN to only be used for traffic to that specific server.

Comment: with IP table updates?

Answer (score 0):

Your VPN will have a configuration(you havent said what VPN you're using) to set it as the default gateway or not client side.

If you do push default gateway: All traffic goes over VPN
If you don't push default gateway: Only traffic destined for the other network(where the SMB share is) will go over VPN

Depending on the data you may also save some time by having it compressed on the server before your copy starts. In this situation CPU time is much less scarce than bandwidth.